# Calling a shell script from eclipse that requires sudo password

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I need to call a shell script from eclipse which deploys python files, however, I need to pass in the sudo password, I have managed to bring up a prompt for the password when running the script but dont understand how I can set the root password in the sudo command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers for specific commands

```
<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: <cmd1> [cmd2 [cmd3]]
```

to edit /etc/sudoers you have to use:

```
sudoedit /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 0):

If a graphic can be used, try 'gksudo '. This will prompt for a password and pass it to the sudo command and then execute  with su privileges.

If you want to code it yourself, get the source for gksudo via 'apt-get source gksu' and look at the C code.